# MySQL being attacked with xxx@localhost

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I notice that when I use phpMyAdmin to login mysql, the identity will be xxx@localhost. When I use mysql work bench with .pem sshkey to login mysql, it is also xxx@localhost. Otherwise if I use command line to login mysql, it will be xxx@ip

[image]

from this mysql error log, although I have disabled port 22, 3306, 8080, I still can see someone trying to login mysql with xxx@localhost. I ever though my .pem was stolen, but after I created a new .pem and setup another server with latest version of mysql, it still happens.

is my server being hacked?

Comment: Not really on topic here, but since you have phpmyadmin is it accessible from everywhere?

Comment: Look at your server's other logs (Apache, etc.) to find out which IP address(es) these requests are coming from and block them. If you don't know how to do this, ask your sysadmin for assistance.